# Grab strings before and after inner string in regex Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string like this:

`20 EQUALS 'Value goes here'`

I want to split it up into 3 separate strings:

`conditionField = 20`
`conditionOperation = 'EQUALS'`
`conditionValue = 'Value goes here'`

I tried this to get the Condition Field:

`var conditionField = condition.replace(/(.*)(.*EQUALS)/, '$1');`

But it get's the beginning and the end.

I'm having trouble splitting it up and dealing with the white space and spaces in the value.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: You may try this /(\d*) (EQUALS) (\d*)/g

Comment: What are all possible inputs? `Twenty LESS THAN '21'` is this valid input?

Comment: @Tushar No, the conditionField will always be a number, the operation will never have a space

Comment: Then, do you know the list of possible operations?

Comment: This should work then `/^(\d+)\s+([a-z]+)\s+(.*)$/i`. Use `$1`, `$2` and `$3` to get respective values.

Comment: @binariedMe How would I split up the result into 2 seperate variables? It's clumping the results into one variable.

Comment: @Jordash you should get an array with useful information, you should then assign each variable to correct element from array. Also you should use /(\d*) ([a-zA-Z]*) (\d*)/g  if the condition could be different from "EQUALS"

Comment: Try doing this : var a = string.split(/(\d*) ([a-zA-Z]*) (\d*)/g)
and then conditionField = a[1], conditionOperation = a[2], conditionValue = a[3];

Answer (score 1):

Your question would actually be a bit of challenge if you wanted to arbitrarily extract quoted terms along with individual words.  But since you appear to have a rather fixed structure, starting with a single number, then a single word command, followed by a third term, we can use the following regex pattern here:

```
([^\\s]*)\\s+([^\\s]*)\\s+(.*)
```

Each term in parentheses above will be made available as a capture group after the match has been run.  In this case, I just blanket everything after the first two terms together.

```js
var string = "20 EQUALS 'Value goes here'";

var re = new RegExp("([^\\s]*)\\s+([^\\s]*)\\s+(.*)");
match = re.exec(string);
if (match != null) {
    console.log(match[1])
    console.log(match[2])
    console.log(match[3])
}
```

Comment: I'll recommend using Regex Literal syntax. That way, you don't have to escape those backslashes.

Comment: @Tushar I'd be happy to edit if I even knew what that was :-)  ... 100K doesn't mean I know everything.

Comment: Here's trick: Execute `new RegExp("([^\\s]*)\\s+([^\\s]*)\\s+(.*)")` in browser console and you'll get it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

`var data = '20 EQUALS 30';
var a = data.split(/(\d*) ([a-zA-Z]*) (\d*)/g);
conditionField = a[1];
conditionOperation = a[2];
conditionValue = a[3];`

Comment: Sorry, but "Try this :" + a chunk of code isn't terribly helpful to anyone.